# Recyclerview with match_parent for width and height returns fixed size error

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

When generating an APK/Signed Bundle lintVitalRelease returns this report:

```
<issue
    id="InvalidSetHasFixedSize"
    severity="Fatal"
    message="When using `setHasFixedSize() in an `RecyclerView`, `wrap_content` cannot be used as \&#xA;a value for `size` in the scrolling direction."
    category="Correctness"
    priority="5"
    summary="When using `setHasFixedSize() in an `RecyclerView`, `wrap_content` cannot be used as \&#xA;a value for `size` in the scrolling direction."
    explanation="When a RecyclerView uses `setHasFixedSize(...)` you cannot use `wrap_content` for  size in the scrolling direction."
    errorLine1="        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);"
    errorLine2="        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~">
    <location
        file="/home/Documents/MyProject/app/src/main/java/com/myproject/MainActivity.java"
        line="97"
        column="9"/>
</issue>
```

Which is obviously not true because my layout file looks like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Is lint wrong or did I mess something up?

this became a problem after I integrated kotlin with my java project!

Comment: Try App Bundle, instead of apk, since apk is not required to upload in play store, it does not give any errors.

Comment: Have you resolved this? I've literally removed all wrap_content/0dp instances from my layouts and still seeing this...

Comment: @sinek The problem was with Android Studio/lint. I don't remember how I fixed it but try reseting cache.

Comment: Any working solutions? anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Your error possibly in the code can be this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

In this case we will use my_recycler_view.setHasFixedSize (true)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And in this other my recyclerview.setHasFixedSize (false), this applies if we also use wrap_content as width